# Replacing multiple variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has 800 observations having repeated values of -1 , -0.9 and 2.
I would like to replace all values of -1 with 2, -0.9 with 1 and 2 with 3.
How do i write this as a code in R ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is what you are asking for:

```
#let's create a data frame as example

df <- data.frame(a = c(-1, -0.9, 2), 
b = c(1, 2, -0.9), 
c = c(-0.9, 2, 1))
df

#performing some substitutions
df[df == 2] <- 3
df[df == -1] <- 2
df[df == -0.9] <- 1
df

#you might wrap everything into a function
```

Comment: Yup thats exactly what Im looking for,

Comment: Thank you so much , I'm just learning R and would come up with such questions from time to time

Comment: you are welcome. you can mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can write it in a loop

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can write it in a loop
Example 
my df has 1 column and 800 observations or rows 
these 800 are a mix from range of +1 to -2
if i in df is greater or equal to 1 replace it with 3     
else 
replace it with 0

Comment: hi, you still do not need a loop. For the first condition, I use the column called 'b' from the example, `df$b[df$b >= 1]` matches all the values that are 'greater or equal' to 1; thus, the substitution step is `df$b[df$b >= 1] <- 3`. Similarly, for the other condition `df$b[df$b < 1] <- 0`

Comment: That's much easy to understand and efficient compared to the loops, Thanks a lot